# How to know from what module user was called

Tags: ruby, class, module, call

I have 2 modules and 1 class:

```
module B
  def hi
    say 'hi'
  end
end

module C
  def say(message)
    puts "#{message} from ???"
  end
end

class A
  include B
  include C
end

A.new.hi
#=> hi from ???"
```

How i can get message as `hi from B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use [`caller_locations`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations) to determine the calling method's name, and use that information to retrieve the method's [`owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html#method-i-owner):

```
module C
  def say(message)
    method_name = caller_locations(1, 1)[0].base_label
    method_owner = method(method_name).owner
    puts "#{message} from #{method_owner}"
  end
end
```

But this is very brittle. It would be much easier to simply pass the calling module, e.g.:

```
module B
  def hi
    say 'hi', B
  end
end

module C
  def say(message, mod)
    puts "#{message} from #{mod}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thinking on second answer, that's a decorator pattern?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Kenel#`__method__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) with [Method#`owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-owner):

```
module C
  def say(message)
    puts "#{message} from #{method(__method__).owner }"
  end
end

class A
  include C
end

A.new.say('hello')
#=> hello from C
```

[Kenel#`__method__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__):

> Returns the name at the definition of the current method as a Symbol.
>   If called outside of a method, it returns nil.

[Method#`owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-owner):

> Returns the class or module that defines the method.

Comment: You don't need `self`.

Comment: @sawa yeap, fixed :)

Comment: @dgmike because this example has `include C`, not `include B`. Define `module B`, add the `say` method as I showed, create new class, nclude module B and see that it does :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko that's the point, `module C` must find `module B` across method call.

Comment: A small point: you don't actually need `owner` (with MRI anyway). If you remove `.owner`, `hi from #<Method: A(C)#say>` is printed. The owner,`C`, is shown in parentheses.

Comment: @dgmike understood. IMO this does not make sense as long as you have access to modules definitions. Instead of hard metaprogramming just go with [Stefan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan)'s suggestion - pass module's name to method - done